# Find limit of $\frac{1}{x} \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n} i\prod\limits_{k=0}^i\frac1{1+k/x}$ when $n\to\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> I need to find the limit of following series,
>   $$u_n(x) = \frac{1}{x+1} + \frac{2}{(x+1)(x+2)} + \frac{3}{(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)} + ... \frac{nx^{n-1}}{(x+1)(x+2)...(x+n)}$$
>   $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} u_n(x)\ ?$$

My attempt:
 I tried writing this in following equivalent form by taking $x$ common from denominator.
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{x} \sum_{i=0}^{n}  \frac{i}{\prod_{k=0}^{i} (1+ \frac{k}{x})}$$

Comment: $$\frac1x\sum_{i=0}^ni\prod\limits_{k=0}^i\frac1{1+k/x}=1-\prod_{k=0}^n\frac1{1+ k/x}\to1$$

Comment: @Did Could you explain your answer a bit, How your LHS and RHS are equal?

Comment: you should take $x^i$ from the denominator

Comment: are you sure there's only an x^n term at the end?

Comment: something may be wrong https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+i+%3D+1+to+n+of+i*x!%2F(x%2Bi)!

Comment: Raindeer: Sorry but did you even try to prove the exact formula in my comment, say, by induction on $n$? This does not seem like rocket science, does it?

Comment: @Raindeer You can prove that identity by taking LCM and clearing denominators, the resulting polynomial in x will be of degree n but have n+1 roots, hence identity. Another way is to use partial fraction decomposition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did's comment is surely the most rapid and elegant way, but we may see another technique. Note that $$\prod_{k=0}^{i}\left(1+\frac{k}{x}\right)=x^{-i}\left(x+1\right)_{i}$$ where $\left(x\right)_{m}$ is the [Pochhammer symbol](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PochhammerSymbol.html). So $$S\left(x\right)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{x}\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{i}{\prod_{k=0}^{i}\left(1+\frac{k}{x}\right)}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{x^{i}i}{\left(x\right)_{i+1}}=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{i}i}{\left(x\right)_{i+1}}.$$ Now recalling that the [lower incomplete gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function) can be written as $$\gamma\left(s,x\right)=x^{s}e^{-x}\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{x^{k}}{\left(s\right)_{k+1}}$$ we get $$S\left(x\right)=\left[x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\gamma\left(s,x\right)e^{x}x^{-s}\right)\right]_{s=x}=\frac{x}{x}=\color{red}{1}.$$